# L() notation in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors

This might be a really simple question, but I just didn't find an answer from anywhere.

I'm teaching linear algebra to myself and in my study material I came upon notation that I just don't understand. I can't find an explanation for it from my material and it is hard to find on the internet as well it seems.

Example:

$U = L((3,2,-6,4),(0,4,1,-5))$

What does the L() notation mean? U itself should be a subspace for ℝ⁴. I would assume that those are vectors within the L().

Comment: It could be what is in other places called "span", i.e. the set (space) of all linear combinations of those two vectors. But I don't actually know.

Comment: Well, I must say that without context on what $L$ is, I don't really know. Given that $U$ is a subspace, the thing that comes to mind is that span of the vectors in $L$, but I have not seen this notation before.

Comment: I have never seen that notation, but my guess is $L()$ the subspace spanned by the vectors within the parentheses; that is the subspace of all linear combinations of those

Comment: I have seen the notation before, and it meant the span of the vectors inside the parentheses. So it's very likely that it's the meaning here too.

Comment: My best guess is what was already mentioned: "linear span". Also denoed by "Span( - )" or $\langle \dots \rangle$

Comment: I'm quite confident that @DanielFischer is correct (as are many others of you as well), that would make very much sense. I knew it was something very simple like this. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the commenters: it's most likely the linear span ($L$ for *linear*) of the vectors in parenthesis.  But that is from context rather than from convention.

In general, the best place to look for the answer to a question like this is the materials you are studying from.

When you take a course, you get a textbook and/or lecture notes.  Those texts are designed to be coherent and consistent.  The definitions and notations may vary from text to text.  Notation is calculus has pretty much been standardized, but less so in linear algebra.

When you're self-studying, I think you need to work in the same way. Concentrate on your one source.  If there is a definition or notation you don't understand, work backwards until its first usage.  There you'll find its meaning.

Comment: I agree, that is the meaning, it makes sense. Therefore it is equivalent to U = span((3,2,−6,4),(0,4,1,−5)). Also, thank you for the tips. I did go through all the material I have been using and it used this notation only twice without explaining it. Still, now that I think of it, I should have been able to guess it.